# Отрисовка графика зависимость силы кулона от расстояния

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plotly

подскажите пожалуйста как отрисовать график? зависимость силы от расстояния. Сила Кулона.
код:

```
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

q1 = pow(10, -9)
q2 = 2 * pow(10, -9)
e = 1
e0 =8.85 * pow(10, -12)
R = 0.02

while R <= 0.1:
F = (q1*q2)/(4*3.14*e0*e*R*R)
print('R=', R, 'F=', F)
R = R + 0.02


plt.plot(R, F)
plt.xlabel('F')
plt.ylabel('x')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для построения графика plt.plot() нужно передать в него два массива, а вы передаете два числа. Вместо (или вместе с) print(R, F) в цикле добавляйте текущие значения в соответствующие массивы R_array, F_array.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код и/или ошибки в виде скриншотов. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1271017/edit))

Comment: а прошу прощения ,я вообще хотела код скинуть, но была ошибка, stackoverflow не допускал из-за каких-то неполадок...(

Comment: сейчас скину тут код:

Comment: @EzikBro  подскажите как это сделать? буду очень благодарна...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Елена, вам не нужны никакие циклы.

Для массивов `numpy` реализованы поэлементные арифметические операции. Пусть `R = linspace(0.02,0.1, 6)` - массив из шести точек от 0.02 до 0.1 с шагом 0.02.

Тогда `R2 = R*R` - это массив из шести точек, каждая из которых есть произведение соответствующих точек из `R`: `R2[i] == R[i]*R[i]`. Более того, `R3 = 1/R2` - это массив, состоящий из обратных квадратов: `R3[i] = 1/(R[i]*R[i])`

Соответственно, для того, чтобы посчитать силу Кулона в каждой из точек массива `R` достаточно написать выражение `F = k*q1*q2/(R*R)`. `F` - это массив, каждый элемент которого связан с соответствующим элементом `R` кулоновским законом: `F[i] = k*q1*q2/(R[i]*R[i])`.

Соответственно, ваша программа без цикла будет выглядеть вот так:

```
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

q1 = 1e-9 # То же самое, что 10 в степени -9
q2 = 2e-9 # то же самое, что 2 на 10 в степени -9
e = 1
e0 =8.85e-12
k = 1/(4*math.pi*e0) # посчитаем k отдельно, чтобы формула выглядела попроще.

R = linspace(0.02, 0.1, 20) # массив из 20 значений R от 0.02 до 0.1

#while R <= 0.1:
#    F = (q1*q2)/(4*3.14*e0*e*R*R)
#    print('R=', R, 'F=', F)
#    R = R + 0.02
# Вместо цикла посчитаем одной формулой
F = k*q1*q2/(R*R) # для всех 20 значений R посчитается одновременно, без цикла

# массив значений R и соответствующий ему массив значений F
plt.plot(R, F)  
# Вдоль оси Х у нас откладываются значения расстояния
plt.xlabel('R') 
# А вдоль Y - Значения силы.
plt.ylabel('F') 
plt.show()
```

[image: F(R)]

Если хотите получить более плавный график, измените число точек в R. Например, `R=linspace(0.02,0.1, 100)`.

Comment: Благодарю! теперь буду знать

Answer (score 1):

Я собрал значения `R` и `F`, которые вы считаете, в списки, чтобы их можно было нарисовать графиком. Только похоже у вас оси `x` и `y` подписаны неправильно, я поменял подписи на как мне кажется правильные.

```
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np

q1 = pow(10, -9)
q2 = 2 * pow(10, -9)
e = 1
e0 =8.85 * pow(10, -12)
R = 0.02
x = [] # добавлено
y = [] # добавлено

while R <= 0.1:
    F = (q1*q2)/(4*3.14*e0*e*R*R)
    print('R=', R, 'F=', F)
    x.append(R) # добавлено
    y.append(F) # добавлено
    R = R + 0.02

plt.plot(x, y) # изменено
plt.xlabel('R') # изменено
plt.ylabel('F') # изменено
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: точно, спасибо вам большое! Вот только теперь вопрос с точки зрения физики...) мне казалось будет прямая зависимость график сам. Вот не уверенна, что так...

Comment: @Елена Тут в знаменателе `R^2`, как это может быть прямой зависимостью? Зависимость обратная и не линейная. )

Comment: @Елена И да, с расстоянием все силы убывают, кроме сил конфайнмента кварков в ядре.

Comment: все разобралась теперь! спасибо вам!!!